# Pulseaudio & Alsa "flicker" on external mic input

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, alsa, elementary-os, microphone

I've got external earphones with a microphone (and a play/pause button) that connect to my Asus laptop through a standard 3.5mm jack. The earphones work fine on other devices. Here on a fresh install of eOS though, everytime there's input from the earphones' mic or button, pulse and alsa "flicker" (in pavucontrol, both input and output device fields flicker between external and built-in devices). There's also choppy sound coming from the speakers/earphones, as if pulseaudio is repeatedly restarted.

This is the output of `pulseaudio -v` for when the flickering happens:

```
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Successfully enabled deferred volume.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Hardware volume ranges from -16.50 dB to 66.00 dB.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Fixing base volume to -66.00 dB
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Using hardware volume control. Hardware dB scale supported.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Using hardware mute control.
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Changed port of source 1 "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" to analog-input-mic
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring volume for source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring mute state for source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled deferred volume.
```

These lines are repeated several times.

What I've tried doing: Jack retasking with hdajackretask, but the problem is still there.

Is anyone could help I'd be really thankful.